# angular select - option values with JSON object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angular-ngmodel

I have a `<select>` with an `ng-model`. I want the values of my `<option>`s to be JSON objects.

When a user selects an option, I want to display individual properties from the selected object.

I have the following [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/etuQXiS4XXTb1VJblLk2?p=preview) showing what I am trying to achieve.

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl as vm">

    <div>
        Person: 
        <select ng-model="vm.person">
            <option value='{"name": "Matt", "age": "21"}'>Matt</option>
            <option value='{"name": "John", "age": "22"}'>John</option>
        </select>
    </div>


    <br>
    Person: <input type="text" ng-model="vm.person">
    Name: <input type="text" ng-model="vm.person.name">
    Age: <input type="text" ng-model="vm.person.age">

</div>
```

The issue is that `vm.person` is a string, not an object, so I cannot access properties of it.

I have tried [fromJson](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.fromJson) but that throws an error because it is non assignable (which is sensible).

```
<input type="text" ng-model="angular.fromJson(vm.person.name)">
```

I could watch for a change on `vm.person`, then do an `angular.fromJson` there, but that doesn't feel right. It feels like there is a better way.

I essentially want to parse the string before it gets to the model, so that by the time it get's to the model, it is a javascript object. This will allow me to access properties of that object.

What is the correct way to handle this in angular?

If there is no "angular" way, what is the common way to handle this in Javascript?

---

EDIT

A [forked plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/q0YRGBI29wiwrdJJseAc?p=preview) to show the effects of adding a `$scope.$watch`.

```
function myCtrl($scope){
    var vm = this;

    $scope.$watch('vm.person', function(){
        vm.person = angular.fromJson(vm.person);
    })
}
```

This allows the Name and Age inputs to be populated correctly, but it breaks the select (it isn't populated by the selected value anymore because the model is changed).

Comment: why not retrieving the `vm` as json format? not a string?

Comment: @EuphoriaGrogi I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Retrieving the vm from where?

Comment: can you show me your controller and service if you have?

Comment: There is a link to a plunker in the question. My controller has nothing in it, for the sake of simplicity, let's assume the values of my options are hard coded JSON strings. I have no service, this is just a simple example.

Comment: read first angular two-way binding, the properties you specified in ng-model directives must be declared in the scope of your controller, unless you leave this controller empty

Comment: I think you can create a directive to convert it in the form you want . I mean pass person to directive and it will assign the required value e.g name

Comment: @EuphoriaGrogi I don't think that is correct, unless I misunderstand you. As you can see from the plunker, the input with the `ng-model` of `vm.person` is populated with the string. The `<select>` has a `ng-model` too. The `vm.person` property is populated, it's just that it is populated with a string whereas I want an object.

Comment: @AjinderSingh How would you go about that? Care to edit the plunker or provide an answer?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Why option you have is a string?

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/bmWg3EnS0LdysTuu4ofs?p=preview
please check

Comment: @EuphoriaGrogi An interesting use of `ng-change`. I hadn't considered that. Unfortunately this still requires a "manual" manipulation of this data to add it to the `vm.name` and `vm.age` rather than just setting it on the model on the `<select>`.

Comment: @MattLishman - i'll edit the plunker to give you a hint

Comment: @MattLishman - Check this https://plnkr.co/edit/IWIFRg?p=preview

Comment: @AjinderSingh If you think this is an answer, please consider adding it as one. Then we can comment on that answer. We need to avoid extended discussion in the comments.

Comment: @MattLishman SO is not the place where everyone will spoon feed you, you should learn it by experience

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about using **ng-options**, You can pass the **object** from the `controller` and then have the select on the basis of that.

**HTML:**

```
 <div ng-controller="myCtrl as vm">
   <select ng-options="selected.name for selected in vm.person" ng-model="vm.customPerson">
      <option value="" disabled>Person</option>
   </select>
   <br>
   <br>
   Person: <input type="text" ng-model="vm.customPerson">
   <br>
   Name: <input type="text" ng-model="vm.customPerson.name">
   <br>
   Age: <input type="text" ng-model="vm.customPerson.age">
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('myCtrl',
function($scope){
  this.person=[
      {name: 'Matt',    age: '12'},
      {name: 'John',     age: '23'},
    ];
});
```

I hope the following **Plunker** satisfies what you are intending to get.

**PLUNKER:**http://plnkr.co/edit/rU5vW5KuvJNJOr7tSOPq?p=preview

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was trying to do. This is the cleanest solution in my opinion.

Comment: I am glad i could be of some service to you :)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if you want the results in this way only.
You can achieve the results you want after changing the code to below,

Controller code:

script.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('myCtrl', myCtrl);

function myCtrl() {

var self = this;
self.persons = [];
self.persons[0] = {
    "name": "Matt",
    "age": "21"
};
self.persons[1] = {
    "name": "John",
    "age": "22"
};
self.personSelected = personSelected;

function personSelected(personName) {
    var i = 0;
    console.log("Person selected called..")
    self.selectedPerson = {};
    for (i = 0; i < self.persons.length; i++) {
        if (self.persons[i].name == personName) {
            self.selectedPerson = self.persons[i];
            break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

HTML code:

```
<body ng-app="app">
<div ng-controller="myCtrl as vm">

  <div>
     Person: <select ng-model="vm.person" ng-change="vm.personSelected(vm.person)">
       <option>Matt</option>
       <option>John</option>
     </select>
  </div>


  <br>
  Person: <input type="text" ng-model="vm.selectedPerson">
  <br>
  Name: <input type="text" ng-model="vm.selectedPerson.name">
  <br>
  Age: <input type="text" ng-model="vm.selectedPerson.age">

  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is better than nothing, but I was hoping for more of a way to do this without manually having to add things to the `vm.selectedPersons` or equivalent.  Just more of a "set the value on this model and then have the DOM update itself" (as you would if the value was simply a string, not an object)

Comment: May be this can help....  You could have a getter setter function, then on ng-change set the vm.selectedPerson variable there and bind it

Comment: This answer doesn't work for my situation, and I personally don't like the idea of calling a function each time it changes. However, this is still useful for other people so still a +1.

Comment: @NehaSaggam, you wrote good. However, its like killing a fly with a cannon :) +1 for your hardwork. GOD, i reached my voting limit :( sorry about that. will drop by later.